# Cannot build Spring 4 project with Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am going through this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I use Maven for building, so I've fetched the pom.xml linked in the official Spring guide:

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/blob/master/initial/pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-build</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-repo</id>
            <name>Spring Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I get the following error when running *mvn install*

> [ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-build' from the
>   repositories [local (C:\Users\Laszlo_Szucs.m2\repository),
>   spring-snapshots (repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot), central
>   repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin
>   repository -> [Help 1]

**How do I know which version to provide in the pom.xml for this?**

Comment: Take a look at this : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-installation I think maven looks this information up from a parent pom. I am a gradle guy and I would recommend you also move to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot is in pom.xml. If not, Add http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot to maven repository.

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-repo</id>
    <name>Spring Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
</repository>
```

And upgrade the maven to 3.0.5 above.

Comment: I don't understand. http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot is already added with <id>spring-snapshots</id>, and adding the above code to <repositories> does not work either. Maven version is 3.2.1.

Comment: Same error. Full error message:

[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-build' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Laszlo_Szucs\.m2\repository), spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot), central http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

Comment: could you please paste the pom.xml

Comment: although, it is working in my system.. add <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version> for the plugin and try..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot folder and then cleaning the project resolved the issue. After this issue, I also faced another issue in which STS complained that my maven project was not updated. However, right clicking on the issues in the Markers area and selecting Quick Fix popped up a window which prompted me to update the maven projects. Selecting the projects and clicking the update button in this window resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I specified d goals as  "spring-boot:run" (without quote) it works for me
procedure: right click on myproject>run as >run configurations >click on mavenbuild>goals(specify goal name)>run